# Connecting to a Biometric device attached to Server

Tags: c#, networking, fingerprint, biometrics

I have been working with a biometric device for quite some time now. I have always been able to connect a biometric device and fetch the data out of it. But this time I have been giving a very old device (Pegasus PB-7) which is connected to a server. I am only given the remote desktop connection and access to a biometric device. The problem I am facing is that there is already a software installed on a remote desktop and when I provide the Ip and port it connects to it in seconds. But when I use zkemSdk which I have been using to connect to other devices as well, it doesn't connect and the following method returns -7 to me.

```
int idwErrorCode = -1;
this.objCZKEM.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
```

This code is not defined in the SDK manual. I am able to ping the device and telnet works as well. Please give some pointers to what might be the problem.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the device manufaturer?

Comment: They are not responding. I have sent a lot of emails. I think its some network problem to be honest.

Comment: Does it work if you connect locally from the server? If it does, you should consider doing some kind of "proxy" app to support this behavior

Comment: @PedroLuz. I have been given a remote desktop connection and at remote desktop there is already an application running which is connecting in seconds. But if I install any other app it doesn't work. Can you tell me how to do "proxy" for app?

Comment: @SafiMustafa, I don't quite follow, does the code work from within the RDP session? What do you mean if you install any other app?

Comment: @PedroLuz an app that was already installed on remote desktop is working from remote desktop. But we want to get rid of that app as it is very slow. So I made another app using SDK provided by ZKtech. This SDK is commonly used for all the devices in C#. So when I connect a device using app created by me locally (By connecting device through lan cable with my laptop directly), every thing works fine. But when I take my app to remote desktop connection it is unable to connect to the device

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned **objCZKEM** , So i am guessing that you are using a Zkteco brand biometric device.

If you wish to connect to a biometric device located in a remote location, There are a few things that you will require:

1. You will need a Public IP Address for that device ( Normally, Biometric Devices can be used within a network using a local IP, but here you are trying to access a device located in a remote network )
2. By default the Biometric Device will have a port number like 4370 (You have to add this port number in the servers firewall as well, Both Inbound and Outbound )

Comment: I am using some device named pegasus pb7. I have connect devices using objCZKEM many times but no luck with this device. I have also tried AxSBXPC which is for pegasus it returns me "5". I have both the static IP and port number. Telnet works for it, But no SDK is able to connect to the device.

Answer (score 0):

> when I connect a device using app created by me locally (By connecting device through lan cable with my laptop directly), every thing works fine. But when I take my app to remote desktop connection it is unable to connect to the device

It means that, you are out of network where the device is not connected. zk machines are not designed run on the public IP. Hence configuring the public ip in place of the IP+port in the machine, will not help you.

If you want to connect your zk machines from remote, you have go for the ADMS feature enabled zk machines. then find and use WDMS software which is pay by user count. Or you can attach your machine with [camsunit.com](http://www.etscouncil.com/login?mailerResponse=true&orn=stackoverflow&ts=04/08/2017&ornr="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909327/connecting-to-a-biometric-device-attached-to-server"&tpc=CAMS&it=CAMS-website&learnref=http://camsunit.com) which is pay by the machine count; for managing users and getting the reports. If you are willing to develop the software with the help of API, then  you will have to go for Web API as listed at [http://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html](http://www.etscouncil.com/login?mailerResponse=true&orn=stackoverflow&ts=04/08/2017&ornr="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909327/connecting-to-a-biometric-device-attached-to-server"&tpc=CAMS&it=CAMS-API&learnref=http://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html)